# Model to estimate mapping between barometric pressure and altitude

Tags: estimation, modeling

*(I am not sure if this is the right community to ask this question or whether math.stackexchange would be more appropriate. I feel this is the right one but let me know if I should cross-post)*

I'd like to (probabilistically) map barometer data to altitudes. In other words, for a given value of barometric pressure I'd like to have an altitude probability distribution. I do not care about how this distribution is described. It could be given as a histogram, or in a parametric form (e.g., giving only mean and std and assuming a gaussian distribution)

This mapping will be continuously updated based on the information I am receiving. My question is about the framework/model I should work with. Here is what information I have available:

- A value for the current barometric pressure, updated/sampled every second
- A probability distribution for the current altitude, **acquired by means unrelated to barometric pressure**, updated/sampled every second. The probability distribution has the form of a histogram with 0.1-meter buckets.
- Knowledge that pressure decreases with increased altitude at the constant rate of 0.12 hPa/meter (in conditions and scenarios that I am concerned)

This sounds like I already have the information I am looking for (a mapping Pressure -> altitude p.d.f.). But what I want is a framework to combine the multiple samples I have over time into an evolving estimation. Just to be clear: a sample is a pair of (pressure value, altitude distribution).

Imagine the following scenario:

1. I start sampling and for the first sample I get a pressure of $1015\color{red}{.12}$ hPa and an altitude distribution of 1m mean with 0m standard deviation (i.e., I am dead certain that I am at 1m altitude). Does this becomes my model for the duration of my session/experiment? It should not, because...
2. For the second sample I get a pressure of $1015\color{red}{.00}$ hPa and the same altitude distribution as before (1m mean, 0m standard deviation). The first sample would tell me that this new pressure value maps to 2m altitude, but this new sample keeps telling me with the same certainty that my altitude is 1m. My model should get updated taking into account both samples. What is a way to combine these two with minimal assumptions?
3. Then I receive a few more samples that keep saying 1015.00 hPa and 1m. How does my model get updated after each sample?
4. Then I get a sample that has some uncertainty in the altitude. For example 1015.00 hPa altitude distribution: (1m:30%, 1.5m:20%, 2m:50%). How does my model get updated then?

One step towards fusing/combining samples could be to convert all of them into a nominal pressure value using the rate 0.12 hPa/m. So all of our samples would be expressed in some arbitrary value (say the pressure value of the first sample). In the example scenario given above, the second sample would become 1015.12->(0m 0std) and the sample in #4 would become 1015.12_(0m:30%, 0.5m:20%, 1m:50%). How do you combine the altitude distributions though, especially when you have "degenerate" distributions with 0 standard deviation? Probably this requires the assumption of an underlying model. What model can I adopt with the minimal assumptions made?

Finally, while fusing, I'd like to have the ability to give more weight to more recent samples (as the more recent conditions met are more indicative of the current situation). So if the fusing process has a natural way to give different weights to different samples, it's a great bonus.

Any suggestion and advice very welcome!

Comment: Could you tell us more about the practical situation where this arises? It is little to go on here ... any meteorology textbook should give the relationship between pressure and altitude in the standard atmosphere

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have the (partial) relationship already and I do include it in the information available (the 0.12 hPa/meter decrease rate mentioned in the question). So in a sense I have the slope of a  line and I am looking for the intercept. The intercept is changing due to weather and other local phenomena. That's why I am relying on current and local altitude information from other sources. More specifically I (roughly) know where I am and I have detailed altitude maps that give me an altitude based on possible positions.  Or a distribution on altitudes to be more exact.

Comment: I still think we know to little for an answer ... but I would start, maybe, with Kalman filters ... maybe?